# Expansion and simplification of a function f(x) with a binomial of the form (${1-x^n}$)

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

When I have a function $f(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$, how do I express the numerator $(1-x^n)$ as a multiple of the term in the denominator $(1-x)$? i.e., can the numerator be expressed as $(1-x)$$*$$($y$)$

Is that possible? Can binomial expansion be applied here?

Comment: Are there any constraints on what $x$ is? (is it small i.e. $<<1$ etc?  Perhaps there is an asymptotic way to write your equation above.

Comment: There's no constraints as such, but I would like to learn the implications of constraints like $x <<1$ and when $x$ is very high (i.e, it approaches infinity) et al.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $x\ne 1$, Let

$$S=1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-1}. $$
then after simplification,

$$S-xS=1-x^n. $$

thus
$$S=\frac {1-x^n}{1-x} $$

this is known as the sum of a geometric sequence's terms.

$$1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x) $$
$$1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2) $$
By induction,
$$1-x^{n+1}=1-x^n+x^n (1-x) $$
$$=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})+(1-x)x^n$$
$$=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+...+x^n) .$$

Comment: Could you add some more explanation on how you arrived at the expansion? That would be helpful.

Comment: It is just division of polynomials

Comment: @skrowten_hermit it is a classical formula.

Answer (score 0):

$(1-x)\cdot(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})=1-x^n$  using this property if you cancel $1-x$ $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{n-1}$  Does that answer your question?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some more explanation on how you arrived at the expansion.

Comment: Of ı had seen your comment ı would add something like Salahamam_Fatima had. Although ı can make a few additions to it and maybe a little different percperctive. First of all you should get used her induction method e.g $x^6+x^8+...x^{12}$ if you want to formulize this and examples like these which look a little more dapped. What ı can recommend for further understanding is that you write The polynomials upside down.

Comment: Like $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{n-1}$.  And $1-x$ and then meticulously Try to get The first term The x term The x² term until The last one you'll see that they have one common factor until $x^{n-1}$. Further question:  İf that polynomial went to infinity like $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ what would happen when you multiplied it with $1-x$?